Getting initializationError in integration tests when running ./gradlew clean build
I have written some integration tests using test-Containers in my java Spring boot project. I am able to run the test cases through intelliJ and I am able to run them by running my gradle task independently through the command ./gradlew integrationTest.
But when I clean build my project through the command ./gradlew clean build, I am getting initialization error. Full exception :
IntegrationTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:659
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171
                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at BuildInfoFactory.java:47
                        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException at ClassPathResource.java:211

My file structure looks like this :
src
|
|-- main
|-- test
|-- tests-integration
     |
     |-- java
     |-- resources

Below is the source code of how I am defining my integrationTest task in my build.gradle
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file("src/tests-integration/java")
        }
        resources.srcDir file("src/tests-integration/resources")
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    environment "APPLICATION_NAME", "{project_name}"
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

    mustRunAfter test
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

integrationTest.configure {
    onlyIf { !project.hasProperty('skipIntegrationTests') }
}
check.dependsOn(integrationTest)


My suggestion to you is: don't run clean unless you have to.
I've had a careful look at your test configuration at it looks spot on.
I believe there may be a gremlin somewhere associated with clean not running before all other tasks, which looks to have been a known issue that was thought to be fixed in version 7.4 (GitHub). Perhaps you are using a Gradle version prior to 7.4, or you have somehow a task dependency on clean? This could be investigated, if you had a mind to, by taking a close look at the task execution order.
In any case, it shouldn't be necessary to run clean outside of exceptional cases. The task ordering should take care of renewing the inputs and outputs of tasks as and when required, and in the event that isn't working correctly it should be fixed instead of using clean as a sticking plaster.
